# CIFilters inside Dispatch Queue causing memory issue in an ARC enabled project

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

I was running some CIFilters to blur graphics and it was very laggy so I wrapped my code in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /*...*/ });
```

Everything sped up and it ROCKED! Very fast processing, seamless blurring, great!

After about a minute though the app crashes with 250Mb memory (when I don't use dispatch I only use around 50Mb memory consistently because ARC manages it all)

I used ARC for my whole project, so I tried manually managing memory by releasing CIFilters inside my dispatch thread, but xCode keeps returning errors and won't let me manually release since I'm using ARC. At this point it would be an insane hassle to turn off ARC and go through every .m file and manually manage memory.

So how do I specifically manage memory inside dispatch for my CIFilters?

I tried wrapping it all in an `@autoreleasepool { /*...*/ }` (Which ARC strangely allows?) But it did not work. /:

---

Example code inside dispatch thread:

```
        UIImage *theImage5 = imageViewImDealingWith.image;

        CIContext *context5 = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
        CIImage *inputImage5 = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:theImage5.CGImage];

        // setting up Gaussian Blur (we could use one of many filters offered by Core Image)
        CIFilter *filter5 = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
        [filter5 setValue:inputImage5 forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
        [filter5 setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.00f] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
        CIImage *result = [filter5 valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

        // CIGaussianBlur has a tendency to shrink the image a little,
        // this ensures it matches up exactly to the bounds of our original image
        CGImageRef cgImage = [context5 createCGImage:result fromRect:[inputImage5 extent]];


        imageViewImDealingWith.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

        CGImageRelease(cgImage);
        context5 = nil;
        inputImage5 = nil;
        filter5 = nil;
        result = nil;
```

Comment: You can add the -fno-objc-arc flag to a single file in the build phases section of the project build settings.  Other than that I've had good luck with NSOperationQueue and allowing only one process at a time in the queue.  My memory build up situation was resolved with that.

Comment: @Putz1103 How do you modify `NSOperationQueue` to only allow one process at a time? I would add the flag but this is a VERY large .m file with only these CIFilter sections (sprinkled throughout the file) not needing ARC. If I can't find another solution though I will move do this.

Comment: `operationQueue.MaxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;`

Comment: @Putz1103 Adding the CIFilters to the NSOperationQueue didn't fix crashing, still too much memory allocation. Also, it is very laggy where as dispatch is not. /:

Comment: Looking back it occurs to me this might not have been a leak at all, but rather it was just processing so much that memory really did get that high (even with ARC releasing the old processes) Can't recall if I ever fixed this or not

Answer (score 0):

do you release the cgImage?

```
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

Comment: Ah! Yes I do, sorry when I was copy pasting the code I left that out! Adding it in now!